# How to unshorten url using C++

Tags: c++, sockets, url

I want to know how to unshorten url using C++. I am unfamiliar with socket stuff in C++. 
I found http://www.feedsocial.com/lab/tinyurls/reverse-all.php which can do this on webpage, but do not know how to use C++ to automatically do that.

Answer (score 4):

You could use [libcurl](http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/) to make an HTTP request to the shorttened URL. Then, look for a redirect HTTP status code header with the new address.

Answer (score 2):

I think the general thing done (from a very quick look on Google) is that people make a request to the short URL (via curl, wget, an HTTP request, whatever) and then parse the response to get the real URL. For you, you could use something like [libcurl++](http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/cplusplus/) which is a C++ wrapper around libcurl.